# Easiest/Cheapest alternative of an oscilloscope to observe PWM signal, if any

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement

Is there a tool/method that I can make use of instead of an oscilloscope to be able to display or at least gather information such that its frequency and on-off times of a PWM signal, out of a microcontroller let's say. A cheaper alternative, of course.

Comment: A competent DMM? What frequencies are we talking about?

Comment: a logic analyzer

Comment: Use another microcontroller with an UART-USB bridge to your PC

Comment: @winny nothing in excess conditions I guess, probably between few Hz and few kHz, mostly 50 Hz.

Comment: then you've got three workable answers in your comments.

Comment: Is $300 USD outside of your budget? You can get a beginner DSO for that.

Comment: @JYelton I'm afraid it is, but the options in the comments look promising.

Comment: @muyustan ebay is loaded with cheap scopes. Some of them come in kit form and are not hard to make and are pretty cheap. But some are already built and also cheap. And I'm sure there's a "logic probe" device out there. Radio Shack used to sell one. Many include some basic capability at low frequency pulse counting. This is also a [great project for an MSP430](https://forum.43oh.com/topic/3909-msp430f550x-based-logic-analyzer/).

Comment: If the frequencies and voltages are relatively low, how about AC coupling the signal through a small capacitor to a computer's sound card line-in or microphone input? Then use software (Audacity is a decent free one) that shows the waveform. Measure and calculate the duty cycle by hand.

Comment: @spuck I am now downloading audacity, I'll look what kind of a program it is. Can you explaint the reason for AC coupling? The signal will be between 0-3.3 V or 0.5 V, I couldn't understand what kind of a coupling you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few options:

1. Chinese Logic Analyzer. There are knockoffs available of the "Saleae logic 16" for around 50 bucks on ebay. These work great for debugging digital connections. If you can afford it get the genuine one of course.
2. Read the signal with a microcontroller and transmit it over USB as DKNguyen suggested. The simplest would be digital read, then transmit in a loop but that might not be fast enough, in which case you might need to pack multiple samples into 1 character or something like that. You will also need to manage the timing of the samples, while simultaneously transmitting via serial, so the code won't be trivial.
3. Same as 2, but a better way that just occurred to me is this: Don't read and transmit simultaneously. Simply read data into an array, and once the array is full, stop sampling and transmit the captured data over serial.

Comment: If you literally just want a number for the PWM duty cycle, rather than actually graphing something out, you can just have it measure once or a few times and average that, then output a number.

Comment: USB logic analyzers that are basically CY7C68013A eval boards go for around $8-12 actually.  And you can run them with the open source sigrok software.

Comment: +1 for the cheap chinese logic analyzers. They're *really* cheap, and can supposedly handle signals upto 24MHz (although I've never been able to persuade mine togo beyond 8MHz, but that's good for me)

Answer (score 2):

1. For audio range 20~20kHz use the Audio card with free software and make your own custom 10:1 probe with low inductance ground lead  for coil spring 2 pin probe. Hopefully you have Line Input.

[image]  [ref](https://www.zeitnitz.eu/scope_en)

Record on Audacity for exact Voltages and Spectrum Analyzer.up to +/-1V on Line in.
[image]

2. Make a Logic Probe, "0", "1" with Vcc, Gnd and counter with 2^14 to LED.  Use 1 shot to extend short pulses and toggle. (flash)

Comment: What would be the maximum peek-peek voltage which i can measure using Audio card ?

Comment: +/-1V line input typ. stereo thus use an RC matched divider 10:1 or 5:1