# Understand an accelerometer data sheet correctly

Tags: accelerometer, vibration

I want to use an accelerometer to measure vibrations.
Most important for me is the operating frequency range. Reading a sensor data sheet, section dynamic specifications, there is (mostly) nothing written about this frequency range (like e.g. "the sensor measures vibrations in the range of 5 to 1kHz").

Which are the sensor specs I have to look for in order to know if the sensors fulfills my requirements towards freq. range?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to measure this?  accuracy? specs?  Yes Spectral Density is one method, Rise Fall time is another

Comment: It's for condition monitoring

Comment: So you want to measure changes in amplitudes at specific frequencies using an FFT of the signals  . Search here for Audacity

Comment: e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505756/easiest-cheapest-alternative-of-an-oscilloscope-to-observe-pwm-signal-if-any/505770#505770

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure and how much change?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! My question is maybe a bit misleading. My problem is, that if I take look on a sensor data sheet, there is only sometimes (e.g. for a bosch BMA280) information about the bandwith (here e.g. Bandwidths 500 Hz ... 8 Hz). So I know, that I can take the sensor to measure singals form 8 to 500Hz. But mostly there is nothing written about the bandwidth. That's why I search for any other inidcator from a sensor data sheet, from which I get to know in which bandwidth the sensor is operating properly.

Comment: It will respond to 0 Hz or DC with gravity = -1g   without 2nd O LPF -3dB point  ODRmax.unfiltered 2000Hz but there may be aliasing noise above Nyquist rate so use a filter

Comment: @Lorenzooo "bandwidtt 500 Hz ... 8 Hz" means that the bandwidth is adjustable, and you can measure signals in the range of  [0; bandwidht]. If you find your own question misleading, then **edit** it – it's that easy!